# svg image taking space around image without any margin or padding

Tags: svg

I am using `svg` image in my site like this

```
<img width="251" alt="Page Bros Group" src="http://pagebro.agencyhub.co.uk/wp-content/themes/pbg_theme/images/Page Bros Group logo v1.svg">
```

But when i see it in browser, it showing spaces around it.
i tried `margin:0` , `padding:0`, but not working here is the link of site [site](http://pagebro.agencyhub.co.uk/)

Comment: How did you save the SVG? Seems like the padding is part of the SVG.

Comment: coz it has white space.

Comment: It's unclear what space you're talking about. http://jsfiddle.net/0x353oqp/

Comment: @TylerH yes i dont know why it taking white space, even when i open it in paint, it shows me without that space

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay when i open it in paint, there is no whitespcce

Comment: Does MS Paint support svg/transparency? I'm pretty sure it doesn't.

Comment: @TylerH is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Open your SVG file in [**Inkscape**](https://inkscape.org/en/) editor.

Go to `File` > `Document Properties` > `Resize Page to content` > `Resize page to drawing or selection`. It will remove/trim the space around SVG.