# README.md - image in svg with space in the upper and lower margins

Tags: svg, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I am writing a `README.md` which is inserting this `svg` image:

```
Some text

<p align="left">
          <img width="256" height="256" src="https://github.com/DavidCdeB/Trial/blob/master/Images/extract2.svg">
</p>

Other text
```

Some blank space is added in the upper and lower margins, as shown here:

[image]
 <sup>*Fig. 1*</sup>

I have implemented the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333906/svg-image-taking-space-around-image-without-any-margin-or-padding), where it is said that the SVG file has to be opened in Inkscape editor, and then do `Go to File` > `Document Properties` > `Resize Page to content` > `Resize page to drawing or selection`. This removes the space around SVG. However, after doing this, the problem still appears and I continue to see the blank space in the upper and lower margins.

**Update:**

As very well pointed out by @squeamish ossifrage, the native size of the `svg` image is `width="318.978mm" height="97.003448mm"`. Thus, this now explains why the image declared with `width="256" height="256"` lead to an extra spacing.

If in the `<img>` tag I do not specify sizes:

```
Some text

<p align="left">
  <img src="https://github.com/DavidCdeB/Trial/blob/master/Images/extract2.svg">
</p>

Other text
```

I get the following:

[image]
 <sup>*Fig. 2*</sup>

where no extra spacing is seen, but the image is too big.

If I specify `width="318.978mm" height="97.003448mm"` in the `<img>` tag:

```
Some text

<p align="left">
  <img width="318.978mm" height="97.003448mm" src="https://github.com/DavidCdeB/Trial/blob/master/Images/extract2.svg">
</p>

Other text
```

The result is the following:

[image]

<sup>*Fig. 3*</sup>

which is much better size.

Now, this is an interesting thing: if the `svg` has native dimensions of `width="318.978mm" height="97.003448mm"`, why when explicitly declaring `width="318.978mm" height="97.003448mm"` in the `<img` tag the image is  resized so much (Fig. 3) with respect to what happens if no specification is declared (Fig. 2) ?

Comment: You're trying to insert the SVG image into a square container, but the SVG is far from square: `width="318.978mm"` `height="97.003448mm"`. Try using something like `width="319" height="97"` in your `<img>` tag and see if that helps.

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage Thank you for your comment and for your help. How have you sorted out the dimensions to be `width="318.978mm"` `height="97.003448mm"` ?

Comment: [It's right there at the top of your SVG file.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DavidCdeB/Trial/master/Images/extract2.svg)

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage Thank you for your comment. Let me explain it: It is very clear that the SVG has `width="318.978mm"` and height="97.003448mm"`. Now, if you do not declare dimensions in the `<img` tag, you get the native image, as it is (Fig. 2). If you do specify `width="318.978mm" height="97.003448mm"` in the `<img` tag, you should get the same result. On the contrary, you get (Fig. 3)

Comment: The `width` and `height` attributes of an `<img>` tag must be specified in pixels. Putting `width="318.978mm" height="97.003448mm"` in an `<img>` tag, as you appear to have done, is invalid markup and will cause unpredictable behaviour. Also, you should be aware that the GitHub's markdown editor adds a `max-width: 100%;` rule to embedded images, so your image will never exceed the page width unless you override this setting. If you have further questions about HTML markup and CSS styling, I think it would be a good idea to ask separately, as this question is getting rather out of hand.

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage Thanks a lot for your comment. I understand now that `<img>` tag works in terms of `px` and not `mm`. This all makes now more sense. Now, given the fact that the SVG is `width="318.978mm" height="97.003448mm"`, I wonder how did you came with the suggestion of `width="319" height="97"` ? because effectively this means 319px vs 97px. I wonder how did you came up with those numbers (319px vs 97px) for scaling an image given in 318.978mm vs 97.003448mm ?

Answer (score 1):

> why when explicitly declaring width="318.978mm" height="97.003448mm" in the img tag the image is resized so much (Fig. 3) with respect to what happens if no specification is declared (Fig. 2) ?

It is because the SVG file has a width of 318.978mm, not 318.978px.

318.978mm is equal to 1205.586px.

The reason why `<img width="318.978mm" height="97.003448mm" ...` gives you a 318x97 image is because the `width` and `height` attributes of `<img>` are defined as being values *in pixels*. So the `mm` is being ignored.

See the section "4.8.18 Dimension attributes" in the [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content-other.html#attr-dim-width).

Comment: Yes, we agree that the SGV file has native dimensions of `width="318.978mm" height="97.003448mm"`... In other words: If you do not declare dimensions in the `<img` tag, you get the native image, as it is (Fig. 2). If you do specify  `width="318.978mm" height="97.003448mm"` in the `<img` tag, you should get the same result. On the contrary, you get (Fig. 3)

Comment: Ah. I see what you mean. I have updated my answer with an explanation for that.